# Easy way to add info buttons (?)

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add those little buttons many webpages have that are simply a circle with a ? on the middle and that on click show a little dialog with information. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Can you point us to some example you like, you might get better answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LKDD8/)?

This could be done with jQuery, [an example here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). ([see demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html))

And many more with google [here](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=jquery+tootl&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+tooltip).

Good luck!!

---

You said javascirpt not Query so [here it goes](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/). See demo [here](http://sandbox.leigeber.com/tooltip/).

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Just a question is there any way to make the one in plain html show the info only on click instead of mouseover? Or at least make it show it instantly instead after a second. Thanks

Comment: @Liso22 I`ll try to show you something similar in jsfiddle, see this here too http://bonrouge.com/br.php?page=cssonclickswitch#n

Comment: Ok, I wasn`t clear enough, there is no only HTML way to make it after a click, so you can do it with CSS like the one I showed you but it is not an actual tooltip, so you might as weel go with javascript, not sure which approach do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going for the jquery one.

Comment: I commented without refreshing the page and only saw your comments afterwards. The jquery one worked as a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `title` HTML attribute for a rollover message?  Otherwise, I'm sure there are easy ways to make those with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is probably what you're looking for. It's a JavaScript framework that has many plugins available, some of which do what you want.

One is http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html. You can search for others at http://plugins.jquery.com/ or by searching google for "jquery tooltip".

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with jquery & css. Lot of example out there. [image]

1. [jQuery Tooltip](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip)
2. [CSS Tooltip](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+tooltip)

I suggest to use [Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) :)